# Linking clusters and masks by a common identifier

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, nearest-neighbor

In ArcMap, I have raster clusters with unique identifiers. Around each cluster I have masks.

Is there any way to carry each of the clusters' identifiers over to the attribute table of its closest mask?

I would like to be able to distinguish to which cluster each mask belongs.

Comment: You can convert them to polygons and use proximity tools. With rasters only use euclidean allocation and zonal statistics (majority).

Comment: Thanks, I think I now have a solution and it's in line with your advice. I ended up converting to a polygon but made sure to keep simplify unchecked so that I can convert it back. Then I used spatial join and marked "closest." Next I converted the shapefile back to a raster using the new id as the raster value.